# How to return string composed of superscript inside of fraction for matplotlib legend label?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts, label, legend

I have coded a routine that plots `x` and `y` data. This code also calculates the indices at which the nth derivative `d/dx^n (y)` changes sign, where `n` is specified as a function argument. I would like to include this derivative as a legend label in a matplotlib figure.

I can create a label to include this if it is predetermined. As an example, if `n` was pre-determined to be `2`, then:

```
label = r'$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$'
```

But since `n` is a function argument, I do not know how to assign it to the fraction. As an example (containing failed attempts), see below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = x

def f(x, y, n):
    """ """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    if n == 1:
        label = r'$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$'
    else:
        numerator = 'd^{}y'.format(n)
        denominator = 'dx^{}'.format(n)
        # label = r'$\frac{}{}$'.format(numerator, denominator)
        # label = '$\frac{}{}$'.format(numerator, denominator)
        # label = '$\frac{numerator}{denominator}$'
        label = r'$\frac{numerator}{denominator}$'
    ax.scatter(x, y, c='r', marker='.', s=5, label=label)
    ax.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig)

f(x, y, n=1)
f(x, y, n=2)
```

I am only concerned with the legend label. How can I make it such that I get the desired output of a string fraction, the numerator of which appears as `r'$d^ny$'` and the denominator of which appears as `r'$dx^n$'` (where `n` is a number)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the string formatting syntax `%s` as following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = x

def f(x, y, n):
    """ """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    if n == 1:
        label = r'$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$'
    else:
        numerator = 'd^{}y'.format(n)
        denominator = 'dx^{}'.format(n)
        label = r'$\frac{%s}{%s}$' %(numerator, denominator)
    ax.scatter(x, y, c='r', marker='.', s=5, label=label)
    ax.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=18)
    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig)
```

[image]